# compare two list of dictionaries and update list with missing key value pair

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, dictionary

I have two list dictionaries'

```
L1 =  [{'y': 3L, 'x': u'2016-10'}, {'y': 3L, 'x': u'2016-12'}]
L2 = [{'y': 0, 'x': '2016-12'}, {'y': 0, 'x': '2016-11'}, {'y': 0, 'x': '2016-10'}]
```

Compare these two list with value of `x`.

**Final out put like:**

```
output= [{'y': 3L, 'x': '2016-12'}, {'y': 0, 'x': '2016-11'}, {'y': 3L, 'x': '2016-10'}]
```

How can i do it?

Comment: While you may be _using_ Oddo 8, your question isn't necessarily about it. Please make sure to tag appropriately :)

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not sure what you want. Would you be willing to edit your question to provide more details? Specifically, how did you arrive at the output in the example?

Comment: how to compare?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enjoy:

```
L1 =  [{'y': 3L, 'x': u'2016-10'}, {'y': 3L, 'x': u'2016-12'}]
L2 = [{'y': 0, 'x': '2016-12'}, {'y': 0, 'x': '2016-11'}, {'y': 0, 'x': '2016-10'}]

output = []
for e2 in L2:
    found = False
    for e1 in L1:
        if e1['x'] == e2['x']:
            output.append(e1)
            found = True
            break
    if not found:
        output.append(e2)

print output # output= [{'y': 3L, 'x': '2016-12'}, {'y': 0, 'x': '2016-11'}, {'y': 3L, 'x': '2016-10'}]
```