# Compare two list and making new list with missing items

Tags: python, list, dictionary, compare

how can i compare the two list dataset and make a new dataset with missing value.

```
lis1=[{'a':'1','b':'2','c':'3','d':'4','e':'5'}]
lis2=[{'a':'1','b':'2'}]
```

i tried the follow code

```
lis3=set(lis2)-set(lis1)
```

but it make this error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

also i found this post and tried to use the code but it also didnt work with mine:
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41235613/compare-two-list-of-dictionaries-and-update-list-with-missing-key-value-pair)

i appreciate from your support

Comment: this is a list with a dict inside it: `lis2=[{'a':'1','b':'2'}]`

Comment: yes, data set type is list but inside have dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you have two dictionaries and not two lists, so

```
dict(set(lis1[0].items()) ^ set(lis2[0].items()))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try '-' too:

```
print(dict(set(lis1[0].items())-set(lis2[0].items())))
```

output:

```
{'d': '4', 'e': '5', 'c': '3'}
```